# Dojo and dijit.Dialog not centered

Tags: dojo

I have a little problem with Dijit.Dialog.

I have some dialogs, which have a small size, and they are displayed in the center of my screen, so it's ok.

But I have also a Dialog with a height of 550px, and it's not displayed in the center of my screen but in the bottom : the browser scroll to the bottom and then displayed it.

I create the dialog simply by:

```
var dialogLodge = new dijit.Dialog({
    id      : "dialogLodge",
    style       : "width:700px;height:550px",
    title       : "Create lodge",
    href        : "/lodge/create.html",
    preload         : true,
    draggable   : false,
    onCancel    : function(){
        …
    },
    onLoad      : function(){
        …
    },
});
dialogLodge.startup();
```

So I don't know why it's not displayed at the center.

If anyone has an idea,

Thanks.

PS : I use Dojo 1.6.1 and I tested it with the 1.7 too

Comment: It works fine in my machine... why are you calling startup() instead of show() by the way ? What browser are you using ? What theme ?

Comment: well thanks, if I call show() instead of startup() it's works.

Comment: Good... so I'll put that as an answer so that you can vote up if you don't mind ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a dialog puts a dom node in your page with css styles that hide it (display:none; visibility:hidden).

In order to make your dialog visible, you should use dialog.show().

You can use dialog.hide() to make it invisible again (and it will remain available in case you want to show it back).