# dijit.dialog opening in the bottom of the page for the first time

Tags: dialog, dojo

I have a dijit dialog created declaratively in my static html page.

If I open this dialog as soon as my page is loaded it opens properly in the center of the page, but if I perform some actions available on the page and then load the dialog then the dialog gets padded to the bottom of the page.

This happens ONLY THE FIRST TIME the dialog is loaded and ONLY if the first time happens to be after performing some actions on the page. All the other times the dialog is loaded properly in the center of the page.

There's a similar question here:
[Dojo and dijit.Dialog not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419290/dojo-and-dijit-dialog-not-centered)

but the solution given there is not working for me because I'm already using dialog.startup() and dialog.show().

This happens in Firefox, Chrome and IE and I'm using Dojo 1.8